# How can I download an image from Azure Blob Storage and store it into a local directory?

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

So here is the general situation. I have a directory inside an Azure blob storage container called `dir`. There are multiple images within this directory. Let's say they are `img1.png`, `img2.png`, and so on. I want to take these images from the blob storage and store them in a local repository called `localDir`.

I want to be able to do this in an iterative fashion where I loop through each image inside `dir` and store it in `localDir`. That way, I can easily skip over some images. I also need to be able to do this with the latest version of `azure-storage-blob`, which would be version 12.8.0, if I'm not mistaken.

Assuming that I have the `container_name` and `connect_str`. Here is the code so far,

```py
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

img_blob_list = container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with='dir/')

for blob in img_blob_list:
    img_blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob=blob['name'])
```

With this code I can obtain the `img_blob_client` for each image in the Azure `dir` blob. However, I do not understand how to take this image and copy it into the local directory `localDir`. I have tried to do the following:

```py
for blob in img_blob_list:
    img_blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob=blob['name'])
    with open(f"./localDir/{blob['name']}", "wb") as dst:
        dst.write(img_blob_client.download_blob().readall())
```

After running this code, the files appeared in the desired destination folder as expected. However, they wouldn't open or render at all.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I was able to run your code successfully and was able to open the files. Here's the code I used: https://gist.github.com/gmantri/48c9c58aedd765af11f1e226edd6ab14.

Comment: The code is correct. Can you check the files in the blob? Are they intact ？

Comment: @PamelaPeng Thank you very much. It turned out the files in the blob storage hadn't been stored correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could upload Blob following the code:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=upload_blob_name)

# Upload the local file
with open(upload_file_path, "rb") as data:
    blob_client.upload_blob(data)
```